# Property binding to the object does not work in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, property-binding

I'm having the very strange behavior with Angular 2 property binding.

Firstly, this is a Store class:

```
export class Store {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
}
```

This is component code:

```
export class MyBuggyComponent implements OnInit {

  stores: Store[];
  selectedStore: any;
  error: any;

  constructor(private myDataService: MyDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDataService.getStores().subscribe(
      stores => this.stores = stores,
      error => { this.error = error; console.log(this.error); });
  }

  selectionChanged(value: any){
    console.log("DEBUG: " + value);
  }
}
```

And here is the template that drives me nuts!

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="store">Select store:</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select" id="store" name="store" required 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedStore" (change)="selectionChanged($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let s of stores" [value]="s">{{s.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <small class="form-text text-muted" *ngIf="selectedStore">Address: {{selectedStore.address}}</small>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here the binding `[value]="s"` of the `option` of `<select>` tag just does not work! It sets `selectedStore` to some empty object(?), It displays empty `Address:` text in `<small>` tag, and it logs: `DEBUG: [object Object]` in console (in `selectionChanged()`). But the `{{s.name}}` interpolation works as expected (displays names inside select-box).

Now watch this: if I make following modification to the template, it just works as expected:

```
  <option *ngFor="let s of stores" [value]="s.address">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
<small class="form-text text-muted" *ngIf="selectedStore">Address: {{selectedStore}}</small>
```

Now the binding works, the address is logged in console and also displayed in `<small>` tag properly. So the binding `[value]="s"` does not work (actually gives some weird 'object' value), but binding `[value]="s.address"` works as expected. I've followed the docs and there is no mention of such limitation. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[value]` only supports string vales as the bound value. Use `[ngValue]` instead, it can bind objects.

Comment: I think this should be clearly documented in official docs, which it is not as of this posting.

Answer (score -1):

i have same issue, you can try my solution:

```
<select class="form-control custom-select" id="store" name="store" required 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedStore" (change)="selectionChanged($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let s of stores; let i = index" value="{{i}}">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>

// .ts
selectionChanged(value: any){
   // this.selectedStore = position in stores
   console.log(this.stores[this.selectedStore]);
}
```